# Initialize hover ussd session from web app

Tags: javascript, android-webview

I'm working on a small web app project and I have build a react native webview to facilitate mobile users the access the app.

I heard about hover USSD that allows to automate USSD sessions and I'm interested to know if there's a possibility to initialize a hover USSD session from my web app when the user clicks on a given button.

I'm trying to initialize hover USSD session from an Android Webview but I really don't know if it's something possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a straight forward documentation how to intergrate it in android app. Go for it